# C++ Array numbers from the biggest to the smallest

Tags: c++, arrays

i am a begginer programmer in c++. I found a very interesting exercise in an old c++ book, which doesn't have the solution for that exercise, so i hope you guys can help me:

It wants me to create a deck of 52 cards, then shuffle the deck and deal the cards to 4 players:

This is an example of the code:

```
cout << "Player 1: ";
for (int j=0; j<13; j++)
{
     card[j].display();
     cout << ", ";
}
```

> Player 1: 8, 7, 3, 2, A, K, 5, 4, Q, 9, 3, A, 2

Now it wants me to array those numbers from the biggest to smallest: 
A, A, K, Q, 9 ,8, 7,5 ,4, 3, 3,2, 2

After having done a research on the internet, i learnt how to find the biggest number of an array, but i still don't know how to array those numbers from the biggest to smallest. I am using GNU Compiler.

Thanks.

For those who want to all the code, here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

enum Suit {clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades};

class deck
{
private:
    int number;
    Suit suit;
public:
    void setcards(int n, Suit s)
        { number = n; suit = s; }

    void display();
};

void deck::display()
{
     if (number >= 2 && number <= 10)
    cout << number;
    else
        switch(number)
    {
        case 11: cout << "J"; break;
        case 12: cout << "Q"; break;
        case 13: cout << "K"; break;
        case 14: cout << "A"; break;
    }
    switch(suit)
    {
        case clubs:    cout << static_cast <char> (5); break;
        case diamonds: cout << static_cast <char> (4); break;
        case hearts:   cout << static_cast <char> (3); break;
        case spades:   cout << static_cast <char> (6); break;
    }
}

class game
{
private:
    int j;
    enum {cardmax = 52};
    deck card[cardmax];
public:
    game()
    {
        for (int j=0; j<cardmax; j++)
        {
            int num = (j % 13) + 2;
            Suit su = Suit(j / 13);
            card[j].setcards(num, su);
        }
    }

    void shuffle()
    {
        char ans;

        cout << "Would you like to shuffle the deck? (y/n): ";
        cin >> ans;
        if (ans == 'y')
        {
            srand(time(NULL));
            for (j=0; j<cardmax; j++)
            {
                int k = rand() % 52;
                deck temp = card[j];
                card[j] = card[k];
                card[k] = temp;
            }
        }
        else if (ans =='n')
            deal();
    }

    void deal();
};

void game::deal()
{
    const char esc = 27;
    const char enter = '\r';
    char ans;

    cout << "Press ESCAPE to exit the game or ENTER to deal: ";
    ans = getche();
    if (ans == esc)
        exit(0);
    else if (ans == enter)
    {
        cout << "\n\nPlayer 1: ";
        for (j=0; j<13; j++)
        {
            card[j].display();
            cout << ", ";
        }
        cout << "\nPlayer 2: ";
        for (j=13; j<26; j++)
        {
            card[j].display();
            cout << ", ";
        }
        cout << "\nPlayer 3: ";
        for (j=26; j<39; j++)
        {
            card[j].display();
            cout << ", ";
        }
        cout << "\nPlayer 4: ";
        for (j=39; j<52; j++)
        {
            card[j].display();
            cout << ", ";
        }
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nWould you like to deal again? (y/n): ";
        cin >> ans;
        if (ans == 'y')
        {
            shuffle();
            deal();
        }
        else if (ans == 'n')
            exit(0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    game cards;
    cards.shuffle();
    cards.deal();
}
```

Comment: The word you are looking for is "sort" :-) You're asking how to sort an array.

Comment: Those aren't numbers, unless you count in base27! :-)

Comment: @xanatos If it is truly base 27 then 10 > Q > K > J > A.

Comment: whatever, how can i sort an array?

Comment: @xanatos: I suspect J, Q, K, A are represented internally as `11`, `12`, `13`, `14`.

Comment: @KennyTM If it was truly base27 you would need another 14 cards :-) Thirteen if you count the Jocker.

Comment: @Cameron It wouldn't work very well, because A would be 14, but then the A value often changes based on the position. QKA but A23

Comment: @NikolaidisDimitris It would be easier if you showed us your code, especially how the data is kept inside the `card` :-) And even what card is... a `std::Array`, a `std::Vector`, a `Card[]`..

Comment: I suggest you to use numbers 14, 13, 12, 11 instead of A, K, Q, J. Then you can use Bubble sorting algorithm (I think this is easier to beginners) to sort the array.

Comment: Ok i will, hang on a moment, i am posting all the code... yes, J,Q,K,A are respesented as 11, 12, 13, 14

Comment: i used the numbers 11,12,13,14, they are just displayed as J,Q,K,A

Comment: all you have to do is implement operator < in your deck class and use std::sort

Comment: You might consider having an array per player otherwise you'll need to sort the 4 parts of the array separately.

Comment: uuhm, what values does the function sort takes?

Comment: The reason i cannot use an array for each player is that it would be impossible for a player to get 2 times the same card (e.g. 9, 9)

Comment: Yes, if you used 4 arrays you'd need to fill them from a single 52 card deck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to implement the less than operator in your deck class like so:

```
class deck {
    //...
    bool operator < (const deck& other) const {return number < other.number;}
    //...
}
```

Then I'd suggest turning that array of cards in a std::vector

```
std::vector<deck> card;
card.resize(cardmax);
//instead of
deck card[cardmax];
```

Then you can sort the std::vector like so

```
std::sort(card.begin(), card.end());
```

Note that in order to use the std::vector type, you have to add `#include <vector>` somewhere in the file where you are using it and in order to use std::sort, you have to add a `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: Are you sure it is that complicated? This book doesn't mention anything about the operator < or soft...so there must be onother easier way...

Comment: You can also use the qsort function from the standard C library, but this is faster. Plus it's really not that complicated, you just need to add 4 lines of code

Answer (score 1):

Look up `std::sort`.

You should be able to apply it to your array:

```
   std::sort(&card[0], &card[cardmax]);
```

If you want to order the cards in a different manner, you will have to write a function that will change the order.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/?kw=sort

```
comp
    Binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments, and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go before the second in the specific strict weak ordering it defines.
    The function shall not modify any of its arguments.
    This can either be a function pointer or a function object.
```

Example:

```
class deck
{
  [...]  // All your existing code.
  public:
    static bool descending_order(const deck& first_card, const deck& second_card)
    {
      return first_card.number > second_card.number;
    }
};
```

Comment: In all of this you haven't told him he need to redefine the `operator<` :-)

Comment: @xanatos: Because he doesn't need to. He can pass the comparison function as parameter to sort.

Comment: What's the operator < ??

Comment: But using this method will sort the cards as:

Q, K, A, A, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2

Also you need to overload the `<` operator for deck class otherwise you will run into compile time errors

Comment: @Sebastian Sadly the class has the `number` private, so it wouldn't be accessible unless the comparator is defined inside the class (as `static`). And then the comparator would need to be modified, something like `first_card.number > second_card.number`.

Comment: @Smac89 Why would it result in that order? Given that A is represented as 14, K as 13, Q as 12, and J as 11, it should work properly. Other than for the scope issues that xanatos points out.

Comment: indeed, the number is private, but if that's the problem, i could make it public

Comment: @Sancho, Yup I completely missed the fact that the cards have a different number representation. I was thinking more along the lines of their ascii values

Answer (score 1):

The easiest sorting algorithm to understand in my opinion is the bubblesort.

The algorithm goes like this:(for biggest to smallest)

First it compares elements 0 and 1.
   If (element 0 less than element 1) THEN swap the elements
Then it does the same thing, but with elements 1 and 2.

When you get to the end of the array, if any swaps have been made, you must start back at elements 0 and 1, and work your way across the array again.

I know that may be difficult to understand just reading it, but [HERE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SH8_vOcvLg) is a youtube beginner c++ video that should make it very easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it without too much refactoring.  To go the whole way I'd split the prompts and "deal again" loop outside deal so it wasn't recursive and make the logic so you wouldn't need `exit(0)`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>

//If no c++ 11 you may need to remove the next line
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

enum Suit {clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades};
const char* CardLetters[] = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A" };
const char SuitLetters[] = { 5, 4, 3, 6 };

class deck
{
private:
    int number;
    Suit suit;
public:
    void setcards(int n, Suit s)
    { 
        number = n; suit = s; 
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << std::right<< std::setw(2) << CardLetters[number - 2] << SuitLetters[suit];
    }

    bool operator >(const deck& rhs) const
    {
        //If you have c++ 11, this is cleaner
        //return std::tie(number, suit) > std::tie(rhs.number, rhs.suit);
        //otherwise
        if(number == rhs.number)
        {
            return suit > rhs.suit;
        }
        return number > rhs.number;
    }
};

class game
{
private:
    enum {cardmax = 52};
    deck card[cardmax];
public:
    game()
    {
        for (int j=0; j<cardmax; j++)
        {
            int num = (j % 13) + 2;
            Suit su = Suit(j / 13);
            card[j].setcards(num, su);
        }
    }

    void shuffle()
    {
        char ans;

        cout << "Would you like to shuffle the deck? (y/n): ";
        cin >> ans;
        if (ans == 'y')
        {
            std::random_shuffle(&card[0], &card[cardmax]);
        }
        else if (ans =='n')
        {
            deal();
        }
    }

    void deal();
};

void game::deal()
{
    const char esc = 27;
    const char enter = '\r';

    cout << "Press ESCAPE to exit the game or ENTER to deal: ";
    char ans = getche();
    if (ans == esc)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (ans == enter)
    {
        for(int playernum = 0; playernum < 4; ++playernum)
        {
            const int offset = 13 * playernum;
            std::sort(&card[offset], &card[offset + 13], std::greater<deck>());
            cout << "\n\nPlayer " << (playernum + 1) << ": ";
            for (int j=0; j<13; j++)
            {
                if(j > 0) 
                { 
                    cout << ", ";
                }
                card[offset + j].display();
            }
        }

        cout << "\n\nWould you like to deal again? (y/n): ";
        cin >> ans;
        if (ans == 'y')
        {
            shuffle();
            deal();
        }
        else if (ans == 'n')
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    game cards;
    cards.shuffle();
    cards.deal();
    return 0;
}
```